# Error compiling JSP after using jdk 8

Tags: java, jsp

The error I get is:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: JBWEB004062: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

JBWEB004061: An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from    required .class files
```

I read a lot of posts on the Internet arguing this same problem, and all of them tried to solve it changing eclipse version, or shut-down eclipse and restarting it, or defining in the classpath the workspace default version for JDK.

I tried the first two options and they didn't work, but not the third because I have to use jdk 8 and not 7.

Until I was using JDK 7 it all worked fine.
So, what can I do in order to compile correctly with jdk 8?

Comment: It would be interesting to see your code.

Comment: Which JDK version is being used to run Tomcat?

Comment: @nitind Actually I'm using JBoss 7.0 (EAP 6.2), and it's setted on jdk1.8.0_73

Comment: @AlexR it's an enormous project and I don't even really know which JSP throws the error

Comment: Is there a newer version of JBoss that you can try?

Comment: @nitind No, I have to use exactly that version

Comment: Can you clarify the "until I was using JDK 7" part? Does JDK 7 work fine, or does it emit the same log message?

Comment: @nitind Using JDK7 it works fine without any message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]
It seems I was using an old version of ecj (ecj3.7.2redhat-1.jar). Using a newest version (ecj-4.3.1.jar) and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that when using Eclipse, you are only sometimes using your JDK.  The Eclipse embedded compiler is mostly compatible with the JDK javac executable; except that it is a different compiler (which is sometimes detectable) as it has a bunch of hooks and rewrites to provide the editor feeback popular in Eclipse.

I would look into compiling your JSP on the command line, to simplify if the issue is due to mismatched compilation environments.  At the command line, you are only going to be using the Java tools, so the concern that the Eclipse IDE might not be working in full accordance with the standard disappears.

Comment: The compiler in his IDE isn't involved here, this is happening at runtime on the server.

Comment: @nitind, Is there a chance that someone used a Java8 specific Map call?  For example `getOrDefault(...)` doesn't exist in Java7 and could cause a compiler failure on a Java7 backed web server, which might be misreported as a class not found error.  In this case, even if the code was compiled to Java7 bytecode standards, the runtime would fail due to a missing Java8 version of Map.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in jboss-5.1.0.GA and jboss-eap-5.2 with a system that needs to run on both platforms. You need to replace the file ***jasper-jdt.jar*** in the directory ***/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar*** of your jboss for the ***ecj-4.3.1.jar*** and rename it to jasper-jdt.jar. (Observation: backup the original jasper-jdt.jar before applying changes).

So:
Replace jasper-jdt.jar for ecj-4.3.1.jar renaming ***ecj-4.3.1.jar*** to ***jasper-jdt.jar***.