# Wildfly 8.2.1 JSP engine config(mapped-file) in web.xml fail

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I had a jsp web application comipled with java 1.7 and deployed in JBOSS AS 7.1.1. is fine.

I would like to migrate to Wildfly and choosing Wildfly 8.2.1 with java 1.8. I compiled source and deploy to Wildfly. But it show error for some jsp loading:

```
15:13:24,654 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-11) UT005023: Exception handling request to /Testing3/js/selectionDialog.jsp: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: JBWEB004062: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

JBWEB004061: An error occurred at line: 29 in the generated java file
The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

JBWEB004211: Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:85) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
...
...
```

I had got some idea from other forum and it stated to add the below config code into web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param> 
    <param-name>mappedfile</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```

However, if I add this code into the web.xml, the wildfly will fail to load the java code for jsp. It should be fail to use JSP engine. I search the reason, and found that for wildfly 8.1 version, the above config should be unnecessary. It may caused that problem of JSP engine compliation.

But where is the config for "mappedfile" in Wildfly now?

Below please find my application and server details:

- **Java IDE:** Eclipse oxygen 3 RC3
- **Old JBOSS:** JBOSS AS 7.1.1 (java 1.7)
- **new JBOSS:** Wildfly 8.2.1 (java 1.8)

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of the ejc are you using? (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989057/error-compiling-jsp-after-using-jdk-8)

Comment: Wildfly 8.2.1 using ecj-4.3.1.jar. It seems not the wildfly problem, but the configuration of the web application.